# Eclipse Oxygen Show In > History records path

Tags: eclipse

For Eclipse Oxygen version 4.7.0 for Windows, when you right click on the editor, you'll get a menu with several options (also if you combine Alt + Shift + W). For the Show In > History option (see attached picture), a history record will appear, but those records are not in the folders where the Local History is saved:

- .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history
- .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project

So question is, where are those records saved in Windows? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Assuming you do not use a version control system like Git, SVN, etc: To make sure that the local history is saved to `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history` you have to shutdown Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The History view usually shows history from which ever source control system you are using (SVN, Git, CVS, ....). So the data will be coming from the source control system and probably isn't stored in the .metadata at all.